# What is the technical name for a public key container in DER format?

Tags: reference-request, terminology, pkcs8

I have a public key in the following (format-neutral; the type is specified by the DER bytes) format:

```
$ cat pubkey.der | openssl asn1parse -inform der -i
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 290 cons: SEQUENCE
    4:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons:  SEQUENCE
    6:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim:   OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
   17:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim:   NULL
   19:d=1  hl=4 l= 271 prim:  BIT STRING

$ cat pubkey.der | openssl rsa -inform der -pubin -text
Public-Key: (2048 bit)
Modulus:
    00:ac:f3:c2:c6:60:c2:9b:1e:db:fb:b6:32:67:45:
    09:25:be:b0:d9:66:21:a0:80:ac:52:be:d4:59:1c:
    7f:85:c0:45:ed:4e:85:69:55:80:a9:1e:36:94:93:
    19:ce:30:8b:89:5d:1a:8e:9a:d6:7a:88:6a:1a:68:
    6d:72:57:5e:11:a2:ec:9e:44:b7:64:06:6a:1c:d0:
    81:b2:18:cb:a1:82:7f:ef:ad:ef:1a:61:52:46:54:
    d0:50:1f:73:14:ad:2c:8e:4c:d8:90:74:9a:f5:37:
    e7:54:91:3b:79:0a:2e:af:7e:f3:de:98:1c:3c:fd:
    d6:67:73:63:7b:10:7d:b7:77:04:ab:42:17:33:4d:
    28:79:ed:4c:a1:96:71:94:32:bf:2d:49:d6:bd:b2:
    c5:26:42:ad:3e:f4:bb:8e:e8:70:1d:7f:cc:3b:a6:
    04:6c:be:6f:1a:a2:40:c4:a5:ee:d5:83:87:44:a5:
    90:22:c5:96:14:69:3c:ae:65:76:9c:45:41:4b:5f:
    04:03:27:b6:74:a5:3b:c4:27:d4:83:7c:0a:18:b4:
    5d:36:95:6f:9b:08:f4:14:37:8d:33:be:bd:e0:46:
    11:89:9e:f9:5b:49:f7:9e:c6:2f:86:5e:96:83:5e:
    47:9c:c0:3a:60:91:ea:41:98:7f:3e:85:a5:ab:73:
    b0:59
Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
writing RSA key
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEArPPCxmDCmx7b+7YyZ0UJ
Jb6w2WYhoICsUr7UWRx/hcBF7U6FaVWAqR42lJMZzjCLiV0ajprWeohqGmhtclde
EaLsnkS3ZAZqHNCBshjLoYJ/763vGmFSRlTQUB9zFK0sjkzYkHSa9TfnVJE7eQou
r37z3pgcPP3WZ3NjexB9t3cEq0IXM00oee1MoZZxlDK/LUnWvbLFJkKtPvS7juhw
HX/MO6YEbL5vGqJAxKXu1YOHRKWQIsWWFGk8rmV2nEVBS18EAye2dKU7xCfUg3wK
GLRdNpVvmwj0FDeNM7694EYRiZ75W0n3nsYvhl6Wg15HnMA6YJHqQZh/PoWlq3Ow
WQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

What is the technical name for this format? I keep wanting to call it [PKCS#8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5208), but I think that would be incorrect, since PKCS#8 is a private key format. What do we name the PKCS#8 equivalent DER format for public keys?

Comment: The format is PKCS#1 with PEM encoding. Your question is however off topic here.

Comment: @HenrickHellström, the question of off/on topic aside, I don't necessarily agree. First, it's DER, not PEM. (the contents of the PEM header in my example are not relevant to the discussion.) Second, I checked [RFC 3447 (PKCS#1 v2.1)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3447) and didn't see any mention of this particular format. To be specific, section A.1.1 mentions the public key syntax, but not the PKCS#8-like wrapping my example exhibits. (see the `rsaEncryption` OID in the `asn1parse` output.)

Comment: Well, you don't have to take my word for it. All you have to do is to implement a Base64 decoder, an ASN.1 parser, a DER parser and see for yourself, just like I did. :)

Comment: @HenrickHellström, I have been doing pretty much exactly that, and I don't know what to call this code module. PKCS#1 certainly doesn't fit. This format can clearly be used for non-RSA key types.

Comment: Just to be clear (and as I mentioned in a previous comment), you are correct that PKCS#1 specifies the contents of the `BIT STRING` shown in my example. But I'm asking what the name of the *entire* object is.

Comment: If it's not a plain PKCS#1 RSAPublicKey, it is probably a SubjectPublicKeyInfo from PKIX/X.509

Comment: @HenrickHellström, [bingo](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.1), that is exactly what this is. Thank you. If you make that an answer, I will accept it. (for what it's worth)

Comment: I do not agree with the close votes. This is not about decoding or decrypting a piece of ciphertext, it is about identifying a cryptography related data structure. That is both a concise question and of use to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As can be seen by [RFC 5280 (X.509)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1), this structure is the `SubjectPublicKeyInfo`. This field is formatted as follows:

```
SubjectPublicKeyInfo  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
     algorithm            AlgorithmIdentifier,
     subjectPublicKey     BIT STRING  }
```

The `AlgorithmIdentifier` is defined as follows:

```
AlgorithmIdentifier  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
     algorithm               OBJECT IDENTIFIER,
     parameters              ANY DEFINED BY algorithm OPTIONAL  }
```

The above two types define the format of the outer container in the ASN.1 in question (with the `NULL` value corresponding to the `parameters` field). The `BIT STRING` is an inner object defined by [Appendix A.1.1 of PKCS #1 v2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#appendix-A.1.1) as follows:

```
RSAPublicKey ::= SEQUENCE {
    modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
    publicExponent    INTEGER   -- e
}
```